# Practice question...

Tags: probability, statistics

Harvey the clumsy waiter is in trouble at work because he has been breaking too many
dishes. Suppose that the number of dishes he breaks follows a Poisson distribution with
a rate of 0.11 per hour. Harvey works an 8-hour shift today, and his boss has warned him
that if he breaks any dishes during the shift, he will be red. What is the probability
that Harvey will be red today?

Wouldn't lambda be lambda*t = 0.11 x 8 = 0.88? Or did I get that twisted?

Comment: Yes, you have the appropriate $\lambda$.

Comment: I'm not getting the correct answer though. The way I set it up is that the probability that he breaks one dish i.e P(X=1) = (.88^1 * e^-.88)/1! is wrong- I'm lost when it comes to setting up the equation.

Comment: Probability he will not be "red" (??) is $e^{-\lambda}$. No dishes broken. Probability of red is $1-e^{-\lambda}$. That's the probability of breaking $1$ **or more** dishes. You were calculating probability of breaking *exactly* $1$. Please report success.

Comment: That gave me the correct answer, but I don't understand how it's 1−e^−λ

Comment: The term $e^{-\lambda}$ is the probability that $X$, the number of broken dishes, is $0$. So $1-e^{-\lambda}$ is the probability that more than $0$ dishes are broken. If you want to do it the hard way, find the probability number of broken dishes is $1$ (you had done that), $2$, $3$, $4$, and add up. You will get the same correct number, with a lot more work.

Comment: Oh okay, now I see. Thanks a bunch!